# Fix MP4 files which were improperly stopped while recording due to lack of space?

Tags: mp4

I have used my Android cell phone to record online lectures while driving home. The problem is that the version of Android across all my devices is 32 bit, so the maximum file size is limited.  Because of this I now have dozens of MP4 files which cannot be played because they were not properly closed out (no EOF given).  I've tried:
Arista Transcoder
Avidemux & Avidemux 2.6 (GTK+, QT and Jobs)
Flowblade Movie Editor
Handbrake
Kdenlive
LiVES
OpenShot Video Editor
Pitivi
Transmageddon Movie Transcriber
VLC
But with no useful result.

How does one restore playability to MP4 files which were improperly stopped while recording?
My last idea is to try Testdisk to see if it can produce functional MP4 files from the existing non-functional files (I've avoided it so far because of the volume of time and space it requires to even attempt as much).

Thank you,
David

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't have any damaged m4a files of my own to try this out on but, [here](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/27182/how-to-recover-audio-from-an-incomplete-or-corrupted-aac-m4a-file) this is reported to have worked for some:

```
ffmpeg -i damagedfile.mp4 -c copy fixedfile.aac
```

I'm not sure if the fixed file has to be `.aac` format or can be `.mp4` like the original. I would try `.mp4` for the output file first if it was me.

From the same link there are repair services that can reportedly charge $90 to fix an `.mp4` file but I would avoid that.

Comment: The problem the files have actually prevent suggestion from working: terminal response "moov atom not found "damagedfilename".mp4: Invalid data found when processing input"
Result's same no matter file type tried.
This's problem w/ MP4 - Everything must be perfect or file = junk. I've 273.4GB wasted space due to it.  Trouble is LG G5 has all 64bit hardware yet LG only releases 32 bit OS's.  If they'd issued 64 bit then issue wouldn't exist.